# How to extract the expression of smooth function from a generalized additive model

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I have a problem extracting the expression of fitted smooth function in generalized additive model.

I fitted a additive model like this:

```
library(mgcv)
model <- gam(y ~ x1 + x2 + s(x3, bs = "cr"), data = newdata)
```

I could plot the fitted smooth function of `s(x3)`, but I want get the exact expression for it and get its derivative. How can I manage to achieve that?

Comment: Refer to this if you want to recreate a predict plot for GAM. http://zevross.com/blog/2014/09/15/recreate-the-gam-partial-regression-smooth-plots-from-r-package-mgcv-with-a-little-style/

Comment: The smoother is non-parametric. Which part of "non-parametric" don't you understand?

Comment: I mean if given the coefficient and the knots of the fitted smooth function, I presume it has the form like y=a*x1+b*x2+c*(x3-k1)^3+d*(x3-k2)^3+..., I wanna extract this expression from the fitted model

Comment: Look at the examples in `help("predict.gam")`. The part "Differentiating the smooths in a model (with CIs for derivatives)" should be useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot to your help, especially Roland. I manage to get the approxiamate derivatives from your suggestion.